# Do all iOS framework and classes are available to use in Watch App Extension?

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos

I am creating a POC in WatchKit and I found that I can use classes like `OperationQueue`, `Set`, `Dictionary`, `Array`, `Data` etc in my Watch App Extension.

Does anyone know if all the iOS frameworks are included in WatchOS also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; some classes are available on both platform and some are not.

Check the right column of the Apple documentation for the class you are interested in.

For example [`Dispatch`](http://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch) is available on watchOS 2.0+ while [`UITableViewCell`](http://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell) is not available on watchOS :

<kbd>[image]</kbd>